# Hive Tables are created from spark but are not visible in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, hivecontext

From spark using:

```
DataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Ignore).format("orc").saveAsTable("myTableName")
```

Table is getting saved I can see using below command's hadoop `fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse\test.db'` where `test` is my database name

> drwxr-xr-x   - psudhir hdfs          0 2016-01-04 05:02
>   /apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/myTableName

but when I trying to check tables in Hive I cannot view them either with command `SHOW TABLES` from hiveContext.

Comment: Is this a internal table?/or U have mentioned as external table some whee

Comment: I didn't get you, " myTableName " is the new table name , sorry I was using SaveMode.Ignore and SaveMode.Errorifxists as creating new table

Comment: what is the content of your hive-conf file you have put under the Spark conf dir? Can you see from Spark Hive tables?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf/
```

This worked for me in a Cloudera quick start Virtual Box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the **hive-site.xml** file (mine is located at /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml) to Spark conf folder (mine is located at /etc/spark/conf/)

```
sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf/
```

Restart Spark and it should work.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to run `INVALIDATE METADATA;` in the hive console to refresh the databases and view your new table.