# HIVE Table available in SPARK but does not show up in Hive CLI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

*This question is a possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591704/hive-tables-are-created-from-spark-but-are-not-visible-in-hive) but the answers given are not satisfactory.*

I 've ran the following simple code on Zeppelin : 
*(Same scenario with pyspark CLI as well)*

```
%spark2.pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/data/data1.csv")
df.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("default.hive_spark");
```

Then :

```
%spark2.pyspark
sqlDF = spark.sql("show tables")
sqlDF.show()
```

It shows :

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+
|database|       tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+----------------+-----------+
| default|      hive_spark|      false|
+--------+----------------+-----------+
```

But when I login to the HIVE CLI (user:hive) this table does not show up :

```
0: jdbc:hive2://ip-xxx.eu-west-3.com>USE default;
0: jdbc:hive2://ip-xxx.eu-west-3.com>SHOW TABLES;

+-----------+
| tab_name  |
+-----------+
| hive_test |
+-----------+
```

I tried

```
sqlContext.uncacheTable("default.hive_spark")
```

I am confused.

Comment: I guess it might have something to do with users / permissions / ACLs...

Comment: Check the HDFS location for the table

Comment: @serge_k ok I will do it but how would it help ?

Comment: The problem might be in different `default` database locations, though if you add hive-site.xml to hive conf directory then the location should be the same. Try also `msck repair table default.hive_spark` in Hive CLI.

Comment: I didn't think `saveAsTable` generated Hive compatible tables

Answer (score 0):

Use HiveWareHouseConnector since you are working with hive2